# Best practices to add background image in all ViewControllers swift ios 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

Previously on ios 10 I hade the following code which works perfect for me.
I just added UIView with UIImage + UIView with specific colour. After testing it on ios 11 I found out that some of the screens have this ImageView on top of the rest UI elements, so whats wrong with that

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureView()
}

func configureView() {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let backgroundImage = getBackgroundImage()
    view.addSubview(backgroundImage)
    view.sendSubview(toBack: backgroundImage)
}

func getBackgroundImage() -> UIView {
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "lemons")
    backgroundImage.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill

    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = black
    backgroundImage.addSubview(backgroundView)

    return backgroundImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating your view controller programmatically (meaning no storyboard or nib), you can add a background image very simply like this:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        setBackground()
    }

    func setBackground() {

        // set image
        let bg = UIImageView()
        bg.image = // some UIImage
        bg.frame = view.bounds
        bg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        bg.clipsToBounds = true
        view.insertSubview(bg, at: 0)

        // set tint
        let tint = UIView()
        tint = view.bounds
        tint = UIColor.red
        tint = 0.5
        view.insertSubview(tint, at: 1)

    }

}
```

Remember, when you create a view controller programmatically, you must create the view controller's actual view, i.e. `view = UIView()`. Furthermore, "core" tasks, like setting a background image, should be done in `loadView` and "finishing-touch" tasks, or tasks that you want to be executed after the view controller has loaded itself entirely into memory, should be executed in `viewDidLoad`. And, of course, configuring the view controller's view property should definitely not be left for last.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your approach - the reason of so much coding - is that on top of uiImage I want to place half-transparent view. And I dont always have viewContorller created programmatically, maybe just few of them programmatically and the rest from storyboard, thats probably a mess

Comment: I updated the answer to include a tint layer. As long as you insert the image at 0 and the tint layer at 1, everything else will be added above them. It's also better practice, in my opinion, to keep your code as modular as you can. So instead of trying to combine the image and the tint layer into one view, keep them separate, which makes future edits much easier and bugs easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Move `configureView()` call from `viewDidLoad` into `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. The latter is inconvenient in that it is called many times in the course of the view controller's life, so use a Bool property to check, so that you only call `configureView()` *once*, the very first time.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

Better to keep it in helper class:

```
static func setBlurBackGround(_ vc:UIViewController){
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BackGround")
        imageView.frame = dBounds
        vc.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
```